# Properties of a matrix that shares the set of real eigenvalues with its inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

For a  $3\times 3$ real matrix, let $c(A)$ denotes the set of real eigenvalues of $A$. Suppose $c(B)=c(B^{-1})$ for a non-singular matrix $B$ with no repeated eigenvalues. Then which of the following are true?

A) $1$ or $-1$ must be an eigenvalue of $B$.

B)$B^2$ must be $I$.

C)$1$ and $-1$ are the only possible real eigenvalues of $B$.

D)$-1$ must be an eigenvalue.

> Let $ t$ be an eigenvalue such that $t=\frac {1}{t}$ $\to$ $t^2=1$ $\to t=1$ or $-1$.Hence  $1$ or $-1$ may be the eigenvalue of $B$.And hence C) seems to be true.Are A)and D) necessarily true? Also $B^2$ and $I$ have eigenvalue $1$.I think, from this we can't say $B^2$ must be $I$.

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: Takie $\;B=I\;$ for a counterexample of (D) . Now, (C) is true, and this follows from $\;\lambda\;$ eigenvalue of invertible matrix $\;B\;$ iff $\;\lambda^{-1}\;$ eigenvalue of $\;B^{-1}\;$  . Also (A) is true, whereas (B) is false (counterexample?)

Comment: But  for B eigenvalues can't be repeated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that as $3$ is odd, there must be at least one real eigenvalue. If there exists only $1$ real eigenvalue, then that eigenvalue must be $\pm 1$ because then the inverse of the eigenvalue also has to be an eigenvalue of $B$ (by supposition). Otherwise there must exist $3$ real eigenvalues, call them $x,y,z$. Then WLOG suppose $x=1/y$ as then $x^{-1}$ and $y^{-1}$ both can be eigenvalues of $B$ and then $z=\pm 1$ is the only possibility (for example, $4,1/4,1$ are perfect eigenvalues of an invertible matrix satisfying all these properties).

**Suppose there is only $1$ real eigenvalue.**

Thus the eigenvalues of $B$ are $\pm 1, a, \bar{a}$ where $a\in\mathbb C$. Let the corresponding eigenvectors be $v_1,v_2,v_3$ respectively. They are linearly independent, so make them an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb C^3$.

Consider $B^2 (v_1)=B(Bv_1)=B(\pm v_1)=v_1$.

Consider $B^2(v_2)=B(Bv_2)=B(av_2)=a^2v_2$ and this will equal $v_2$ iff $a^2=1$. But $a$ is complex, so its square is never real. Hence B cannot hold.

So A, C are true, B,D are false (D is false because $\pm 1$ is the only real eigenvalue, you cannot say that only $-1$ will be the real eigenvalue).

**Now suppose there are $3$ real eigenvalues. Let they be $x,y,z$ and the eigenvectors (orthonormal) be $v_1,v_2,v_3$ with $z=\pm 1$.**

Then, $B^2(v_1)=x^2v_1\neq v_1$ so $B^2\neq I$ in this case.

So in this case, A is true, B is false, C is false and D is false.

Comment: what is the 3rd eigenvalue?

Comment: Please look at the edited answer. This one is correct. You have 2 cases to deal with.

Comment: You do not need to work with all 3 eigenvalues. Once you see that $B^2v\neq v$ for any basis vector $v$ you can immediately conclude that $B^2\neq I$.

Comment: @London Carter: could u plz explain how could u say $B^2(v)=v$ on the first case?

Comment: Let $\lambda$ be any eigenvalue of a matrix $A$ and $v$ be the corresponding eigenvector. Thus $Av=\lambda v$. Then, $A^2v=A(Av)=A(\lambda v)=\lambda Av=\lambda^2 v$. In your case, $\lambda=\pm 1$.